# Why cin.get(char *, int, char t) and cin.getline(char *, int, char t)?

Tags: c++, iostream

The documentation says the cin.get(...) will leave the termination character(parameter t) in the buffer! I am wondering how could this be useful compared to getline(...) which will discard the termination character... BTW, suppose I have char buf[256], how can I flush that buf to cout?

Comment: Please edit your question title: you've already answered "what is the difference"!

Comment: Please don't put a second, unrelated question in the same post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For lines, the terminating newline is considered part of the line, and you generally want to remove it when reading a line.  Convention has determined that the resulting string containing the line *not* contain that newline, however, which is why getline discards it instead of storing it.  (Other languages/libraries don't make the latter decision.)

For things other than lines, the delimiter may not be considered part of the field being extracted, so you want it to be left and later read.

> suppose I have char buf[256], how can I flush that buf to cout?

If that's a C-string (terminated by a \0), then cout << buf;.  Otherwise you can cout.write it as an unformatted sequence of bytes.

Comment: I posted but then deleted a very similar answer, because I couldn't invent a use for it... do you have an example?

Comment: @larsmans: Consider if you were implementing the `tee` program.

Comment: I'd implement `tee` as `char` by `char` copying, relying on iostream buffering, or with fixed-size buffers...